# Oracle MapViewer installation errors

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, glassfish, oracle-map-viewer

Today I installed Oracle EE 11g for Spatial and MapViewer use. I downloaded http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/mapviewer/downloads/mv-downloads-archive-2173414.html version "Oracle Fusion Middleware MapViewer Version 11g ps6 (11.1.1.7.3) - July 2014" QuickStart Kit and i got some really problems with it. After unzip, in readme there is simple to run "runMeFirst.bat" script, but here i got this: [Console log](http://pastebin.com/CGefENnK). In reply I will add server.log, now i need 10 reputions to post more than 2.

I have no idea what should i do to run it up. I will be very pleased for help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you have installed Java 8 but the Glassfish3 included in the package only runs properly with Java 7.

You should install Java 7 and I guess you have to update your JAVA_HOME setting, but I can't say exactly where because I'm not sure which operating system you are using.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I tried to start Oracle MapViewer 12c but it doesnt work too. Should I update JAVA_HOME for my C:\ProgramFiles\java or Mapviewer Java? Will MV 12c work with 11g Oracle DB?

Comment: I don't know if MV 12c works with 11g Oracle DB. You have to update your JAVA_HOME so that it points to your Java 7 installation.